# Split a long string to a customized string

Tags: c#, regex, linq

Hello I have a long string. I want to split it as some kind of format that has many return carrages.
Each line has 5 short words.
Ex.

`string input="'250.0','250.00','250.01','250.02','250.03','250.1','250.10','250.11','250.12','250.13','250.2','250.20','250.21','250.22','250.23','250.3','250.30','250.31','250.32','250.33','250.4','250.40','250.41','250.42','250.43','250.5','250.50','250.51','250.52','250.53','250.6','250.60','250.61','250.62','250.63','250.7','250.70','250.71','250.72','250.73','250.8','250.80','250.81','250.82','250.83','250.9','250.90','250.91','250.92','250.93','357.2','357.20','362.01','362.02','362.03','362.04','362.05','362.06','362.07','366.41','648.0','648.00','648.01','648.02','648.03','648.04'";`

It has 66 short words.

```
string output = "'250.0','250.00','250.01','250.02','250.03',
                 '250.1','250.10','250.11','250.12','250.13',
                 '250.2','250.20','250.21','250.22','250.23',
                 '250.3','250.30','250.31','250.32','250.33',
                 '250.4','250.40','250.41','250.42','250.43',
                 '250.5','250.50','250.51','250.52','250.53',
                 '250.6','250.60','250.61','250.62','250.63',
                 '250.7','250.70','250.71','250.72','250.73',
                 '250.8','250.80','250.81','250.82','250.83',
                 '250.9','250.90','250.91','250.92','250.93',
                 '357.2','357.20','362.01','362.02','362.03',
                 '362.04','362.05','362.06','362.07','366.41',
                 '648.0','648.00','648.01','648.02','648.03',
                 '648.04'";
```

I thought that I have to count char ',' in the string first such as in [the example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/count-characters). But it could be kind of clumsy.

Thanks for advice.

Comment: Are you saying you want to insert a new line charter after every 5th number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i've understood you correctly you want to

- split those words by comma
- group the result into lines where each line contains 5 words
- build a string with `Environment.NewLine` as separator

---

```
string input = "'250.0','250.00','250.01','250.02','250.03','250.1','250.10','250.11','250.12','250.13','250.2','250.20','250.21','250.22','250.23','250.3','250.30','250.31','250.32','250.33','250.4','250.40','250.41','250.42','250.43','250.5','250.50','250.51','250.52','250.53','250.6','250.60','250.61','250.62','250.63','250.7','250.70','250.71','250.72','250.73','250.8','250.80','250.81','250.82','250.83','250.9','250.90','250.91','250.92','250.93','357.2','357.20','362.01','362.02','362.03','362.04','362.05','362.06','362.07','366.41','648.0','648.00','648.01','648.02','648.03','648.04'";
int groupCount = 5; 
var linesGroups = input.Split(',')
    .Select((s, index) => new { str = s, Position = index / groupCount, Index = index })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Position);

StringBuilder outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var grp in linesGroups)
{
    outputBuilder.AppendLine(String.Join(",", grp.Select(x => x.str)));
}
String output = outputBuilder.ToString();
```

**Edit**: The result is:

```
'250.0','250.00','250.01','250.02','250.03'
'250.1','250.10','250.11','250.12','250.13'
'250.2','250.20','250.21','250.22','250.23'
'250.3','250.30','250.31','250.32','250.33'
'250.4','250.40','250.41','250.42','250.43'
'250.5','250.50','250.51','250.52','250.53'
'250.6','250.60','250.61','250.62','250.63'
'250.7','250.70','250.71','250.72','250.73'
'250.8','250.80','250.81','250.82','250.83'
'250.9','250.90','250.91','250.92','250.93'
'357.2','357.20','362.01','362.02','362.03'
'362.04','362.05','362.06','362.07','366.41'
'648.0','648.00','648.01','648.02','648.03'
'648.04'
```

If you want to append every line with a comma(like in your example):

```
foreach (var grp in linesGroups)
{
    outputBuilder.AppendLine(String.Join(",", grp.Select(x => x.str)) + ",");
}
// remove last comma + Environment.NewLine
outputBuilder.Length -= ( 1 + Environment.NewLine.Length );
```

Comment: Yes, I instead want to append every line with a comma but the last one.

Comment: You have to remove the last comma.

Comment: @Love: Edited my answer to show you how. You just need to set the `StringBuilder`'s `Length` accordingly(-3).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to follow the approach from @Tim's deleted (edit: not deleted any more) answer:

1. Split the string into parts by comma (using `string.Split`)
2. Rearrange the obtained parts in any way you need: for example, packing by 5 in a line.

Something like that (not tested):

```
Console.WriteLine("string output =");
var parts = sourceString.Split(',');
int i = 0;
for (; i < parts.Length; i++)
{
    if (i % 5 == 0)
        Console.Write('    "');
    Console.Write(parts[i]);
    Console.Write(',');
    if (i % 5 == 4 && i != parts.Length - 1)
        Console.WriteLine('" +');
}
Console.WriteLine('";');
```

Comment: Would the downvoter be so kind to explain the reasoning behind the silent downvote? (At mods: I'm glad the BB is watching me.)

Comment: I haven't downvoted but `string.Split(sourceString, ',');` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
string[] words = input.Split(','); 
int wordsInString = words.Length;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var input="'250.0','250.00','250.01','250.02','250.03','250.1','250.10','250.11','250.12','250.13','250.2','250.20','250.21','250.22','250.23','250.3','250.30','250.31','250.32','250.33','250.4','250.40','250.41','250.42','250.43','250.5','250.50','250.51','250.52','250.53','250.6','250.60','250.61','250.62','250.63','250.7','250.70','250.71','250.72','250.73','250.8','250.80','250.81','250.82','250.83','250.9','250.90','250.91','250.92','250.93','357.2','357.20','362.01','362.02','362.03','362.04','362.05','362.06','362.07','366.41','648.0','648.00','648.01','648.02','648.03','648.04'";

var wordsArray = input.Split(',');
var sbOutput = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 1; i < wordsArray.Length +1; i++)
{
    sbOutput.AppendFormat("{0},", wordsArray[i-1]);

    if(i % 5 == 0)
        sbOutput.AppendLine();
}

var output = sbOutput.ToString();
```

Comment: Sorry - that's a Linqpad thing - It's a great free tool for writing C# snippets

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> SplitLongString(string input, char separator, int groupSize)
{
    int indexCurrent = 0;
    int indexLastOccurence = 0;
    int separatorCounter = 0;

    foreach (var character in input)
    {
        indexCurrent++;

        if (character == separator)
        {
            separatorCounter++;

            if (separatorCounter % groupSize == 0)
            {
                yield return input.Substring(indexLastOccurence, indexCurrent - indexLastOccurence);
                indexLastOccurence = indexCurrent;
            }
        }
    }

    if (indexCurrent != indexLastOccurence)
    {
        yield return input.Substring(indexLastOccurence, indexCurrent - indexLastOccurence);
    }
}
```

And you would call it:

```
var result = SplitLongString(input, ',', 5);

foreach (var row in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(row);
}
```